# The children with 50% of the height of the parent (unknown height)

Tags: html, css

I want to get something like that
[image]

My idea will solve this. Creating a div with the parent class in it I have another div (which is responsible for the background), and video. 
I do not want to give height, because I want it to be responsive.

```
<div class="parent">

  <div class="child"></div>
  <video class="video" width="auto" height="651" controls>
    <source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TavVZMewpY">
  </video>

</div>

.parent {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.child {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.video {
  position absolute
  left: 50%
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: 50%;
}
```

however, this solution does not work. The video is for the whole width and height of the parent. How to solve this problem and how to use something like in the picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

- Apply `height:50vh` to `.parent`. This make it height always equal to 50% of your browser height.
- Wrap your `video` in the `.child` `div`
- Align the `.child` `div` to bottom center using `flex`
- Apply `transform` to your `.video`, make it move down from its position 50% of its height, this help archived what you want while not breaking the others CSS rule

```css
.parent {
  height: 50vh;
  background: green;
  display:flex;
  /*Align video to center bottom */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end
}

.video {
  height: 100px;
  width:200px;
  background-color: black;
  transform: translateY(50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
     <div class="video"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: You don't need a `position: relative` for the transform